# PHP: Making thumbnail, why do i get these errors?

Tags: php

When i made this function:

```
function makeThumbnail($type, $name, $size, $tmp_name, $thumbSize) {

//make sure this directory is writable!

$path_thumbs = "uploaded_files/";       

//the new width of the resized image, in pixels.

$img_thumb_width = $thumbSize; // 

$extlimit = "yes"; //Limit allowed extensions? (no for all extensions allowed)

//List of allowed extensions if extlimit = yes

$limitedext = array(".gif",".jpg",".png",".jpeg",".bmp");       

//the image -> variables
$file_type = $type;

$file_name = $name;

$file_size = $size; 

$file_tmp = $tmp_name;
//check if you have selected a file.
echo $file_tmp."<br>";
echo $file_name."<br>";
echo $file_type."<br>";
echo $file_size."<br>";

if(!is_uploaded_file($file_tmp)){

echo "Error: Please select a file to upload!. <br>--<a href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]\">back</a>";

exit(); //exit the script and don't process the rest of it!

}

//check the file's extension

$ext = strrchr($file_name,'.');

$ext = strtolower($ext);

//uh-oh! the file extension is not allowed!

if (($extlimit == "yes") && (!in_array($ext,$limitedext))) {

echo "Wrong file extension.  <br>--<a href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]\">back</a>";

exit();

}

//so, whats the file's extension?

$getExt = explode ('.', $file_name);

$file_ext = $getExt[count($getExt)-1];

//create a random file name

$rand_name = md5(time());

$rand_name= rand(0,999999999);

//the new width variable

$ThumbWidth = $img_thumb_width;



/////////////////////////////////

// CREATE THE THUMBNAIL //

////////////////////////////////



//keep image type

if($file_size){

if($file_type == "image/pjpeg" || $file_type == "image/jpeg"){

$new_img = imagecreatefromjpeg($file_tmp);

}elseif($file_type == "image/x-png" || $file_type == "image/png"){

$new_img = imagecreatefrompng($file_tmp);

}elseif($file_type == "image/gif"){

$new_img = imagecreatefromgif($file_tmp);

}

//list the width and height and keep the height ratio.

list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file_tmp);

//calculate the image ratio

$imgratio=$width/$height;

if ($imgratio>1){

$newwidth = $ThumbWidth;

$newheight = $ThumbWidth/$imgratio;

}else{

$newheight = $ThumbWidth;

$newwidth = $ThumbWidth*$imgratio;

}

//function for resize image.

if (function_exists(imagecreatetruecolor)){

$resized_img = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth,$newheight);

}else{

die("Error: Please make sure you have GD library ver 2+");

}

//the resizing is going on here!

imagecopyresampled($resized_img, $new_img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

//finally, save the image

ImageJpeg ($resized_img,"$path_thumbs/$rand_name.$file_ext", 100);

ImageDestroy ($resized_img);

ImageDestroy ($new_img);





}



//ok copy the finished file to the thumbnail directory

// move_uploaded_file ($file_tmp, "$path_big/$rand_name.$file_ext");

/*

Don't want to copy it to a separate directory?

Want to just display the image to the user?

Follow the following steps:



2. Uncomment this code:

/* 

/* UNCOMMENT THIS IF YOU WANT */

echo "OK THUMB " . $thumbSize;

exit();

//*/



//and you should be set!



//success message, redirect to main page.       

$msg = urlencode("$title was uploaded! <a href=\"Resize.php\">Upload More?</a>");
}
```

Then it stopped working, but outside a function, it works good.

As you can see i added "echo $file...." because i wanted to see if they have value, and they do have the right values.

I just get the error Error: Please select a file to upload.

This function is running after an normal upload image script(full size).

When i call the function i do:

```
makeThumbnail($_FILES[$fieldname]['type'], $_FILES[$fieldname]['name'], $_FILES[$fieldname]['size'], $_FILES[$fieldname]['tmp_name'], 100);
```

At my other file where its not in a function, theres no difference only that the variables is:

```
$file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];

$file_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];

$file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];

$file_tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
```

But it should work, I cant find anything wrong, but it doesnt and i keep getting that error. If i remove the is_uploaded_file function, i get a bunch of another errors.

Comment: Some debugging first please. What does a `print_r($_FILES)` contain? Does `$tmp_name` point to an existing file?

Comment: Hi, the filename you pass with the `is_uploaded_file` function is case sensitive, even on windows! On windows PHP tends to use environment variables like %TEMP% to determine the upload folder and these environment variables sometimes have different capitalization then the actual path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are not using `move_uploaded_file()` before calling the function.

Answer (score 0):

I use timthumb to process the image into a thumbnail when it outputs it to screen, instead of when it's uploaded.

It means you only have one file and not one master size and one thumb size. TimThumb reduces the size of the file on serverside so it appears nice and smooth on the browserside. Have a look at it: [TimThumb Link](http://www.darrenhoyt.com/2008/04/02/timthumb-php-script-released/)

Comment: he didn't ask what you use... he asked why his code doesn't work.

Comment: I was actually giving him an alternative way to do the same thing as a plugin. It's not a solution I know, but it is a helpful alternative

Comment: PS: I also checked your link for TimThumb. 777 isn't good permissions for a temp directory, and you may want to look into porting it to imagick for better memory usage.